# Getting 500 Internal server error while installing theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I had bought a theme from themeforest. basic installation works fine i can login to admin panel and do changes, but while adding theme i am getting `500 internal server error`

[ThemeForest Link](https://themeforest.net/item/outstock-magento-2-responsive-furniture-theme/21207400/comments)

System Log

```
[2018-11-01 08:45:02] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 340000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
```

Comment: Please check logs once, there must be something in logs

Answer (score 0):

1. Check server logs
2. Check permission to var, pub, generated
   folder
3. Check if Rewrite mod is enable

Try clearing cache

Comment: still the same error, i updated the answer with system log